# Create observer (LiveData or Flow) without having (Lifecycle Owner and UI)

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, observers

I have the following code for simple room and Dao function.
I am trying to create observer to observe Customers entity table.
I do not have a lifecycle or UI so how to create the observer?

```
data class Customers(
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String,
    val address: String
)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Query("SELECT * FROM Customers")                         //observable
    suspend fun getAllCustomers(): Flow<List<Customers>>    enter code here
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
suspend fun getAllCustomers() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
       var customers = CustomersDao.getAllCustomers()
    }
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```